# extract the max date in dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot, powerbi-desktop

I have a doubt how to extract the max date in a column that it is group by different dates in power pivot?

input :

27/11/2020, 26/11/2020, 01/01/2020

output:

27/11/2020

Can anybody help me in this matter?

Regards,

Comment: did you try to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/max-function-dax?

Comment: yes i have used max function

Comment: and did not returned the max date? are your column as text or as date?

Comment: ofc extrac the max date  but i require from a column that has several dates grouped  and i need to extract the max

Comment: you  mean that you have a column of type string, containing dates separated by commas?

Comment: @sergiom yes thats right, i have those dates separeted by commas. i could do it in power query however i am using a lot of Merges and my process goes slow so much. thats why i need it in PowerPivot

Comment: I'm afraid that the best option would be to do this operation in the data source, if possible, like in an ETL in SQL. The second option is to do it using M in Power Query. Implementing this in DAX would not remove the column with the list of dates, that I suppose is not used elsewhere in the model. Also dax purpose is not to do string processing